# fail to build universal compression function in fish

Tags: linux, shell, compression, fish

i am using fish shell on linux, i would like to write a function applicable to most compression file formats and what i wrote was:

```
function ex
    if test -f $argv[1]
        switch (file $argv[1])
            case '*.tar.bz2'
                tar xjf $argv[1]
            case '*.tar.gz' '*.tgz'
                tar xvf $argv[1]
            case '*.bz2'
                bunzip2 $argv[1]
            case '*.rar'
                unrar x $argv[1]
            case '*.gz'
                gunzip $argv[1]
            case '*.tar'
                tar xf $argv[1]
            case '*.tbz2'
                tar xjf $argv[1]
            case '*.zip'
                unzip $argv[1]
            case '*.Z'
                uncompress $argv[1]
            case '*.7z'
                7z x $argv[1]
        end
    else
        echo "'$argv[1]' is not a valid file"
    end
end
```

however when i apply this to a tar.gz file in fish shell, no error was given, but it was not extracted either. then when i tried to `tar xjf` the file,, it is extracted.

this has been confusing me for a while.

Comment: For `tgz` you want `tar zxf` -- with `z` not `v`

Comment: @glennjackman Actually both GNU tar and BSD tar ignore those options when extracting. They automatically detect the compression method, if any, and decompress without having to be told whether or how. So `tar xf` (or `tar xvf`) is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ex
    if test -f $argv[1]
        set ext (echo $argv[1] | sed 's/.*\.\(tar\.bz2\|tar\.gz\|tgz\|bz2\|rar\|gz\|tar\|tbz2\|zip\|Z\|7z\)$/\1/')
        if test -n $ext
            switch $ext
                case 'tar.bz2'
                    tar xjf $argv[1]
                case 'tar.gz' 'tgz'
                    tar xvf $argv[1]
                case 'bz2'
                    bunzip2 $argv[1]
                case 'rar'
                    unrar x $argv[1]
                case 'gz' ! 'tar.gz' 'tgz'
                    gunzip $argv[1]
                case 'tar'
                    tar xf $argv[1]
                case 'tbz2'
                    tar xjf $argv[1]
                case 'zip'
                    unzip $argv[1]
                case 'Z'
                    uncompress $argv[1]
                case '7z'
                    7z x $argv[1]
                case '*'
                    echo "Unknown file extension: $ext"
            end
        else
            echo "Unrecognized file format: $argv[1]"
        end
    else
        echo "'$argv[1]' is not a valid file"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You are switching on the result of the `file` command, not on the name.